# Compartir carpeta entre Solaris y Windows con samba

Tags: linux, windows, samba, solaris

Quisiera saber como puedo compartir una carpeta entre estos 2 sistemas mediante samba, eh encontrado información en Internet tanto en inglés como en español pero hay varias cosas que ko me quedan claras y no logro avanzar, agregándole a esto que no manejo muy bien los sistemas de Linux. Si me pueden ayudar estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: solaris aun existe ? -)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero un poco de teoria.

## ¿Qué es Samba?


Los protocolos que utilizan Windows y Linux para compartir recursos en un entorno de red, no son compatibles en absoluto, Samba palabras más palabras menos, hace de intermediario entre estos dos para que exista compatibilidad. Samba corre bajo Linux, y perfectamente se comunica de manera nativa con Windows pudiendo compartir recursos y mantener una coexistencia de dos sistemas que no se llevan bien.

Samba es una implementación libre del los protocolos de *Sistema de Archivos de Internet Común* o CIFS desarrollada por Microsoft, ademas Samba no es utilizado solo para compartir recursos entre Windows y Linux, versiones de CIFS y Samba se pueden encontrar en Mac y o Servidores dedicados a gestión de Archivos y recursos entre otros sistemas más.

## ¿Cómo funciona Samba?

Samba entre todos los programas que posee, consta de dos muy clave los cuales son `smbd` y `nmbd`. El trabajo de Samba es administrar 4 servicios básicos:

1. Servicios de archivo e impresión.
2. Autenticación y autorización.
3. Resolución de nombres.
4. Anuncio de servicio

Los *servicios de archivo e impresión* son la base principal de los protocolos CIFS, esta son proporcionados por `smbd`, `smbd` también maneja la *Autenticación y autorización* de "modo de compartir" y "modo de usuario". En pocas palabras, se puede proteger los archivos y servicios compartidos al requerir contraseña para ellos.

- El **modo compartir** es el esquema más simple, se puede asignar una contraseña a un recurso, sea una impresora o un archivo y cualquiera con la contraseña poseera acceso al recurso.
- El **modo usuario** es un esquema mas elaborado y administrable, este requiere de un usuario y contraseña por cada usuario y se le puede denegar el acceso a ciertos usuarios.

El sistema de dominios antes era gestionada por el Sistema de dominio de Windows NT, que proporcionaba un nivel de refinamiento de autenticación para CIFS, ya que solo se necesitaba una sola autenticación por el usuario para que este pudiera tener acceso a todos los recursos autorizados para el. El servidor de dominios NT maneja esto con un servidor de autenticación(No confundir con un dominio NT con un Sistema de nombre de dominio(DNS)).

La *resolución de nombres* y la *navegación* son administrada por `nmbd`. Estos dos servicios gestiona y distribuyen las lista de nombres [NetBios](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS)

## ¿Cómo compartir una carpeta?

Parto del hecho que ya posee instalado Samba en tu equipo, ademas explicarlo acá sería extenso, cada Distro maneja su propio gestor de paquetes, averigua como instalarlo en la distro que estes.

Samba posee un archivo de configuración, su ruta es `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, este archivo como lo acabe de decir, posee toda la configuración de Samba, ademas los parametros de cada carpeta compartida. al final del archivo agregas lo siguiente:

```
[mi recurso Compartido]

comment = nombre de mi carpeta compartida
path = ruta absoluta de la carpeta
browseable = no|yes
guest ok = no|yes
writable = no|yes
valid users = nombre usuario
workgroup = nombre de grupo
```

- en **comment** se agrega un comentario para recordar que carpeta o
  recurso se esta compartiendo.
- en **path** se pone la *ruta absoluta* del recurso a compartir.
- en **browseable** si es un *yes*, determina si cuando se accede a recursos compartidos, la carpeta se muestre, si es un *no*, solo se podría acceder con la ruta absoluta.
- si **guest ok** es un *yes*, se habilita el acceso a invitados, con lo que se podrá acceder a la carpeta sin un usuario, a estos usuarios se les aplicaría los permisos del grupo *otros*.
- **writable** determina si la carpeta es de escritura o de solo lectura.
- en **valid users** se determinan que usuarios o grupo de usuarios tienen acceso al recuros, si son varios usuarios, van separados por una coma, si es un grupo, lleva delante del nombre un arroba(@grupo).
- en **workgroup** se determina el grupo de trabajo, el por defecto es *workgroup*.

Después de realizar la configuración se le debe asignar una contraseña de *acceso al recurso* al usuario o usuarios en **valid users**, esto se realiza de la siguiente manera en la consola de linux como superusuario: `smbpassword -a nombreusuario`.

Por cierto, debes tener corriendo los demonios `smb` y `nmb`.

---

Esta información fue sacada y traducida de [Información sobre Samba](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/SambaIntro.html). Se le agrego opiniones personales, por lo que puede caer en subjetividad y errores.